# laravel routing not working

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I just like to create 2 views in laravel and need to route,
one for root /
and one for about page,

the following code is the route

```
<?php

Route::get('/', array(
    'uses' => 'HomeController@hm'
));

Route::get('about',  array(
    'uses' => 'HomeController@hm2'
));
```

in the above coding, if the url is root, then it works fine, if the url is about, then error
the following is the controller file

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {
public function hm(){
    return View::make("home");
}
public function hm2(){
    return View::make("about");
}

}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: only one index or home page working for the above codings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, **i moved the public directory to root directory and change the paths in bootstrap file**.

Now, **i installed fresh copy** of laravel and its working fine.

Thanks @Jorge.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to rewrite the URL, you need to activate in your Apache server the following module:

```
"LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"
```

For do this:

1) Open the file "httpd.conf" of your Apache server.

2) Find and delete the "#" in the line of: `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

3) Save and restart your Apache server.

Regards.